# Hide/display a link in BuddyPress toolbar based on user role

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, toolbar, buddypress

How do I hide/display a link in BuddyPress toolbar if the user has a particular role?

```
function your_bp_admin_bar_add() {
  global $wp_admin_bar, $bp;

  if ( !bp_use_wp_admin_bar() || defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

  $user_domain = bp_loggedin_user_domain();

  if (current_user_can('lp_teacher')) {

        $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent'  => $bp->my_account_menu_id,
        'id'      => 'my-create-course',
        'title'   => __( 'Create Course', 'your-plugin-domain' ),
        'href'    => trailingslashit( 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=lp_course&tab=course_settings' ),
        'meta'    => array( 'class' => 'menupop' )
      ) );
  }

  $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
    'parent'  => $bp->my_account_menu_id,
    'id'      => 'my-account-dogs',
    'title'   => __( 'Become an Instructor', 'your-plugin-domain' ),
    'href'    => trailingslashit( 'https://mywebsite.com/become-a-teacher-2/' ),
    'meta'    => array( 'class' => 'menupop' )
  ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_admin_bar', 'your_bp_admin_bar_add', 300 );
```

I don't understand why it only displays `Become an Instructor` even when the logged-in user is an instructor. It is supposed to display `Create Course`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why it only displays Become an Instructor even when the logged-in user is an instructor.

Are you sure that the role / capability for instructors is `lp_teacher`?

If you want to only show `Create Course` to instructors, then try adding an `else`:

```
if (current_user_can('lp_teacher')) {

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent'  => $bp->my_account_menu_id,
        'id'      => 'my-create-course',
        'title'   => __( 'Create Course', 'your-plugin-domain' ),
        'href'    => trailingslashit( 'https://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=lp_course&tab=course_settings' ),
        'meta'    => array( 'class' => 'menupop' )
    ) );

} else {

    $wp_admin_bar->add_menu( array(
        'parent'  => $bp->my_account_menu_id,
        'id'      => 'my-account-dogs',
        'title'   => __( 'Become an Instructor', 'your-plugin-domain' ),
        'href'    => trailingslashit( 'https://mywebsite.com/become-a-teacher-2/' ),
        'meta'    => array( 'class' => 'menupop' )
    ) );

}
```